# Determining the infinite elements in a matrix-R

Tags: r

Let Loss be a 500x24 matrix. I control is there any infinite element in i by typing:

```
    > any(abs(Loss==Inf))
[1] TRUE
```

Result says us there is at least one infinite element in the matrix.

So I search the column(s) which consists the infinite element. So I type the below code:

```
  n1<-dim(Loss)[2]
   xx<-sapply(1:n1, function(i) {any(abs(Loss[i])==Inf)})
 > xx
     [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This time it seems that no column consists infinite element.

Why is that? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `which(is.infinite(Loss), arr.ind = TRUE)`?

Comment: If `Loss` really is a matrix (and not a data frame) then `Loss[i]` will always refer to a single element, not a column. Maybe you meant to use `apply`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @r2evans. Your solution solved my problem. joran, apply didn't  wark for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @joran's point was that you are only checking the first `n1` items of the matrix. Perhaps you intended to use `Loss[,i]==Inf` (note the comma) within your inner function? That should produce different results. (Using `*apply` here is unnecessary, as you get significant benefits -- readability  and speed -- from using vectorized calculations. Additionally, `is.infinite` is significantly faster than `x == Inf`, though that's a lesser improvement.)